# How java.uitl.zip.ZipFile caches files in java

Tags: java, caching

When I run the following code for the first time, it is running for nearly 25000ms(i.e. 25 sec) but from second time onward it is taking only 24ms(i.e. 0.024 sec) even I closed the eclipse and reopen to run. Till I restart the machine again, it takes 24ms only. The article http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/compress-1565076.html which says java.uitl.zip.ZipFile caches. how? where it caches? how can I clear that cache?

```
public class Sample
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws ZipException, IOException
    {
        long st = System.currentTimeMillis();
        File dir = new File("C:/temp/packages");
        File[] files = dir.listFiles();
        for(File file : files) {
            ZipFile zfile = new ZipFile(file);
        }
        long et = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.println(et - st);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Close the `ZipFile` using `ZipFile.close`.

Comment: Still the same behavior.